# Why overflow-x:hidden isn't working on my mobile view?

Tags: html, css

So i was creating my sites mobile view and turns out width isn't 100%. It's more than 100%.
I already tried `overflow-x:hidden` and `max-width:100%` but it's not working. 
[Link of the Website](https://hemanthairart.netlify.app/)

[and Link of the Github repo](https://github.com/jv18creator/hemantHairArt)

If I cut the `#home` section mobile width is normal (100%) I tried giving `#home` `overflow-x:hidden` and `max-width:100%`  but still it's not working.
Please tell me what is it that I am doing wrong and how do I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: The issue is only on line no: 383 of style.css `.welcome_text span` you have set width 120% make it 100% and then check your issue will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Aman I didn't noticed that. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<span></span>` tags are making problem in section with `id="home"`. Secondly, in your CSS you have assigned the width as 120% on class `.welcome_text span`, change it to 100% and you are all set.